# Exchange/IIS making Server 2012 unusable due to lack of resources

Tags: windows-server-2012, exchange-2013

I currently have a VM running Windows Server 2012 DC, with 4GB of RAM and a dual core CPU. This machine has Active Directory running, so is also a DNS and DHCP server.

The problem I have is thus: as soon as I install Exchange 2013, the machine is all but unusable. Everything grinds to a halt and rebooting takes forever. Once back up, it's no better.

The best example of how bad it gets is that other machines can't unresolved IPs through it anymore.

Alongside this, I can't access the OWA or ECP either, though I suspect the timeouts are due to the lack of resources.

Task Manager shows almost 100% of RAM is being used, with IIS the main culprit. The CPU usage doesn't look bad until I check the host, and the VirtualBox session is using 100% of the host CPU.

My question: I don't have much experience with IIS - where should I start trying to work this out? How is it using 4GB of RAM?  The VM is also hammering the HDD, presumably paging due to the lack of RAM.

Thoughts?

Comment: 4 gb has not been enough for those roles for several years.

Comment: I fear you're confusing storage and RAM, but point taken.

Comment: doubtful, you can get 16GB easily enough on a laptop these days.

Comment: I doubt that he's confusing the two. I've got an Exchange server running just a mailbox role and using all of 24Gb RAM quite cheerfully. I'd also suggest that the Windows DC role is best left on a dedicated machine (virtual machine, at least) rather than sharing with Exchange.

Comment: Nice edit/delete there from whoever it was. RobM, someone suggested that his phone had more RAM than 4GB, hence my comment.

Comment: So, is the genereal concesus that I may get away with setting up two VMs for this, given that the max I can offer is around 6GB of RAM over the two machines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Microsoft recommends](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996719.aspx) a minimum of 8 GB of RAM for combined mailbox/CAS server. I wouldn't recommend less than that even on Exchange 2010, unless it were in a test environment (I use 4 GB for my 2010 test server).

Like SQL Server, Exchange mailbox servers will appear to use all of the RAM you give it as the Store process will reserve it for use, but if Exchange is not memory-starved, it can back off if the OS or other applications require more.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll take another look at the specs - could I get away with less than 8GB if I used two VMs, I wonder.

Comment: Sorry, my link might not be very visible above, but click on "Microsoft recommends," and expand the Hardware section.

Memory: Varies depending on Exchange roles that are installed. Mailbox: 8 GB minimum, Client Access: 4 GB minimum, Mailbox and Client Access combined 8 GB minimum.

How many mailboxes are you trying to host on this configuration?

Comment: I've not actually set any mailboxes up yet, it was too slow to manage :)

Comment: The reason I asked is that on top of 8 GB of RAM minimum for an all-roles server, we normally add an additional 10 MB per mailbox, so if you had a single all-roles server with 200 users, I would recommend 10 GB of RAM (8 GB + (200 * 10 MB)).